# A True RESTful API | Help needed

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-web-api

I know that a RESTful would have unified API and it treats everything as a resource (*a noun, example a book, a product,...*) and it can be applied with CRUD operations using HTTP Verbs (*GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE,...*)

I am aware of the fact of nouns & verbs.

Now, I am building a Web API that is managing the books and custom analytics of the books like,

1. Which books or categories are searched frequently?
2. Demand vs availability

ASP.Net Web API

BooksController - GET(Odata), PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

PagesController - GET(Odata), PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

BookAnalyticsController - GetFrequentBooks, GetFrequentCategories,...

PageAnalyticsController - GetFrequentPages, GetBookmarkedPages,...

I used Odata to query list by properties and select the properties as well. This will save duplicate **counter-REST** methods like GetBooksByCategory, GetBooksByYear, GetBooksByAuthor,..

Now, you know that BookAnalyticsController and PageAnalyticsController is going to have multiple HTTPGET verbs based on use-cases.

For Books or Pages controller, I can elegantly browse like

GET https://locahost/api/book

GET https://locahost/api/book/id

POST https://locahost/api/book BODY

PUT https://locahost/api/book/id BODY

PATCH https://locahost/api/book/id PARTIALBODY

For BookAnalytics,

GET https://locahost/api/bookanalytics/GetFrequentBooks

GET https://locahost/api/bookanalytics/GetFrequentCategories

IMO, it is kind of looking ugly. How would you make it pure RESTful API for analytics. Please suggest

Comment: You're doing fine.  Don't stop now.  Is "pretty" one of your design criteria?

Comment: Thanks, Robert! I wonder why is it getting downvoted.

Comment: @Robert-Harvey, can I still call my web API, a true RESTful API?

Comment: I think the way it performs is more important than what you call it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, in some of internal web projects. People started using HTTPPOST for GetFrequentBooks(SomeDataModel someDataModel), citing that model needs to be sent by body. From my opinion, I think it would be better to go disintegrate the model as properties HTTGET GetFrequentBooks(SomeProp someProp, OtherProp otherProp) and send it over querystring or URI. Am I correct?

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what your goals are.  What do you mean by "better?"  What goals do you want to achieve by disintegrating the models as properties and sending them over querystring or URI? What does "disintegrating the models" even mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103012/discussion-between-ashokan-sivapragasam-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @RobertHarvey! It is valuable for me to get to the decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RESTful API does not necessarily need to present a CRUD interface. Resources that are computed from other data do not need to support Create, Update or Delete operations, but they can still be presented with a Read interface (HTTP `GET` verb.)

So your structure in general looks nice, but you could improve the names somewhat.

https://gearheart.io/blog/restful-api-design-best-practices/ gives some reasonable naming recommendations. Two should be applied to your names:

- Use plural for nouns, so `books` instead of `book`
- Do not repeat `Get` in resource names, it is already indicated in the HTTP verb GET. The resource names `GetFrequentBooks` and `GetFrequentCategories` should better be `frequent-books` and `frequent-categories` (lowercase and hyphenated pluralized nouns.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarity! So, it is legal to have multiple GET methods in one controller, correct? GET https://locahost/api/bookanalytics/frequent-books, GET https://locahost/api/bookanalytics/frequent-categories

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ASP.Net framework, so I don't know whether one controller can support several endpoints. REST as an architectural style does not specify how service endpoints should be implemented; if it makes sense and is possible given the framework, just go for it. There are other principles that may apply here, such as the single responsibility principle. But this isn't something that REST is concerned with.